# RSA encrypt by PHP and decrypt by C#

Tags: c#, php, rsa, phpseclib

I'm trying to encryption and decrpytion process between C# and PHP.

My C# code:

```
this.EncryptData("123456", 1024, this.PublicKey);

public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] byte_0, int keysize, string publicKey)
{
    byte[] numArray;    
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rSACryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keysize))
    {
        rSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(publicKey);
        numArray = rSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(byte_0, this.bool_0);
    }
    return numArray;
}

public string EncryptData(string string_0, int keysize, string publicKey)
{
    string base64String;
    try
    {
        byte[] numArray = this.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string_0), keysize, publicKey);
        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(numArray);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        base64String = string.Empty;
    }
    return base64String;
}
public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] byte_0, int keysize, string Key)
{
    byte[] numArray;    
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rSACryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keysize))
    {
        rSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(Key);
        numArray = rSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(byte_0, this.bool_0);
    }
    return numArray;
}

public string DecryptData(string string_0, int keysize, string Key)
{
    string str;
    try
    {
        byte[] numArray = this.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(string_0), keysize, Key);
        str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(numArray);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        str = string.Empty;
    }
    return str;
}
```

and my PHP: lib(https://github.com/membersuite/sdk-php/blob/master/APISample/SSOWithSDK/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA_XML.php)

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA_XML();
$plaintext = '123456';
$rsa->loadKeyfromXML($publicKey);
$ciphertext = base64_encode(strrev($rsa->encrypt($plaintext)));
```

code after PHP encrypt cant decrypt by c# code. anyone can help?

Comment: Probably random padding. Have you checked that you can decrypt on either side?

Comment: i update decrypt code

Comment: What does the `strrev` in the PHP code snippet do?  It seems odd, because you don't appear to reverse whatever it does again in the C# before decrypting it.  (I don't use PHP, so have made assumptions about what it's doing.)

Comment: How do you get the key you are using to encrypt with ? Is it a regular code signing certificate, if so, how do you export the public key and do you distribute the public key for decryption in c# ?

Answer (score 1):

Although Microsoft uses little endian notation for numbers, RSA has been defined by [PKCS#1 / RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447). That explicitly defines how to do padding and such, but it also defines how the resulting octet string should look like using [I2OSP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-4.1) or the integer-to-octet-string primitive. This primitive specifies the output as fixed size (key size) byte array in *big endian format*. This is also the encoding that PHP uses, so you should not reverse the output.

In other words, you should not have to use `strrev`.